# Grafana create-plugin tool does not install the latest grafana, react and other libraries

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-api

As we know, to create a plugin, we use the tool @grafana/create-plugin, which quickly scaffolds the necessary structure to work with Grafana and its respective libraries. However, if you use this command now, for example:

> npx @grafana/create-plugin@latest

**It does not install the latest Grafana version and the it's dependencies**.
There are some outdated libraries, including Grafana itself at version 10.0.3. We already have version 10.1.4 available, and React is also outdated as we are now at React 18, not 17.

Am I missing a point? It seems that the tool is simply not updated, and we need to update the libraries in the package.json...

Thanks!